# Sketch - Export layers and keep the layer size?

Tags: layers, export, image-quality, sketch-app

So, I have my layers and when I go to `File > Add Slices For Selection` to slice the images and then export.

They are coming out with the wrong size, if you take the star, it has a width of 40px on the sheet but when I export it the total width of the image is 60px or so.

Is there a away to make the images export and stay the size I set on the canvas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how your slices are set up, but have you tried `Trim transparent pixels` in the Export panel? If your slice has padding around the actual element you want to export, this should automatically remove it for you.

[image: SketchApp Export panel]

Comment: That does it, it took some time to get use to working with Sketch.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey, don't forget to click the tick to mark this answer as correct if it helped you :) that way people who suffer similar problems in the future will know that this fix works :)